# Plot after rounding dataframe column not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, formatting

I am trying to read the whitespace separated values, apply Savitzky-Golay filter to one of the columns, round the column to 6 decimal digits, plot the graph and export the data to the new file. Here is the working code where I commented out the line which makes graph window 'Not responding':

```python
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace = True)

plt.plot(df.index, df.rotram, '-', lw=4)
#plt.plot(df.index, savgol_filter(df.rotram, 21, 3), 'r-', lw=2)

# smooth the 'rotram' column using Savitzky-Golay filter
df.rotram = savgol_filter(df.rotram, 21, 3)

# round to 6 decimal digits
#df.rotram = df.rotram.map('{:.6f}'.format)         # <-- not responding when plotting
#df["rotram"] = df["rotram"].map('{:,.6f}'.format)  # the same as above (not responding when plotting)

# When plot is removed then above rounding works well
plt.plot(df.index, df.rotram, 'r-', lw=2)

df.to_csv('filtered.txt', sep='\t')

plt.show()

print "End"
```

The sample data looks like:

```python
otklon       rotram      lakat           rotnad
-6.240000    -3.317000   -34.445000      16.805000 
-6.633000    -3.501000   -34.519000      17.192000 
-5.099000    -2.742000   -34.456000      15.059000 
-6.148000    -3.396000   -34.281000      17.277000 
-4.797000    -3.032000   -34.851000      16.052000 
-5.446000    -2.964000   -34.459000      15.677000 
-6.341000    -3.490000   -34.934000      17.300000 
-6.508000    -3.465000   -35.030000      16.722000 
-6.513000    -3.505000   -35.018000      16.845000 
-6.455000    -3.501000   -35.302000      16.896000
.
.
.
(more than 20000 lines)
```

The separator in the input file is `space + TAB + space`.

If I uncomment the line `df.rotram = df.rotram.map('{:.6f}'.format)` then program hangs (Not responding) with the empty graph **although saved data is correct**.

If I then remove the line `plt.plot(df.index, df.rotram, 'r-', lw=2)` then the program ends normally.

Although saving the data to file after rounding works well, plotting doesn't :-/

Comment: Better would be to use `df.rotram = df.rotram.round(decimals=6)`

Comment: @coldspeed: You are right, when using `round()` everything works well, thank you! However, I would still like to know why the above code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I assume it does not understand how to plot strings that look like numbers.

Comment: It's strange there isn't an error but the program just hangs :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round your column to the Nth decimal place, use `pd.Series.round` or `np.around`:

```
df.rotram = df.rotram.round(decimals=6)
# Or,
# df.rotram = np.around(df.rotram, decimals=6)
```

---

> However, I would still like to know why the above code doesn't work as
>   expected.

When you call `map`, you convert your numeric column to a string. Pandas will plot this data without making any assumptions. For your sample data, the plot looks hideous:

[image]

Versus, the latter case using `round`:

[image]

The plots are completely different (in the former case, each string is sorted lexicographically and given its own tick on the y-axis).

Comment: Are you saying the program didn't freeze when you tried to use `map`? BTW, when I accidentally uncommented the `map` code after inserting `round()` below the `map`, the error was: `Type error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`, from what it seems as there aren't any strings :-/

Comment: @Chupo_cro I understand what that error is saying, so what you're trying to conclude is not right. str.format will produce a string (and strings can be multiplied by integers - the result is the string replicated N times .... the issue arises when you multiply a string and a float—that operation isn't defined). Anyway, it does not hang for me because I have 10 data points while you have 20,000, and making a plot with 10 ticks is easy (while wrong) while making a plot with 20,000 ticks isn't.